# Update TextView during a loop in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i'm wondring how to update the textview while going into a loop inside **AsyncTask**

 here what i have done:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += bufferLength) {
        pb.setMax(kbfilesize);
        int prog = i/bufferLength;
        pb.setProgress(prog);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        textV.setText(pb.getProgress());
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 100);
        outStream1.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
    }
```

also as i have read that i don't have to use `runOnUiThread` while using `AsyncTask` i can update the UI from the `AsyncTask`, but every time i try to do that i get an exception:

```
05-08 01:12:43.511: W/ResourceType(32344): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
05-08 01:12:43.521: W/dalvikvm(32344): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41eff2a0)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3800)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at com.linesmedia.MainActivity$FileUploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:255)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at com.linesmedia.MainActivity$FileUploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-08 01:12:43.531: E/AndroidRuntime(32344):    ... 4 more
```

also even if i did it using `runOnUiThread` i getanother exception... any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uuuuhhhh.... use `onProgressUpdate()`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)

Comment: Though bclymer has a point, that's the real reason he's getting the error. But he should be using onProgressUpdate anyway.

Comment: Your answer plus bclymer just made the trick , it's working as i expected. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to post a Runnable inside of doInBackground. `AsyncTask` has a method called `onProgressUpdate()` that you should implement for progress updates. This will be called on the UI thread. Implement that method and add `publishProgress()` at the end of your loop.

You also should not be manipulating any UI components (like your progress bar) inside of `doInBackground()`. All of that needs to happen on the UI thread, so do it in `onProgressUpdate()` instead.

Comment: I will give it a try, i'm updating the progressbar inside of `doInBackground()` it's working good tho.

Comment: It may work for ProgressBar, but it's not a habit you should get into.

Comment: The problem is how do i move the buffer value and other INT inside `onProgressUpdate()` while they're in `doInBackground` ? i can't update the progressbar without having a knowlege of the buffer's value.

Comment: You can pass a value to `publishProgress`. You must declare the type of the argument as the second parameterized type of your AsyncTask. In this case you would use `Integer` as the type. The javadoc for AsyncTask shows an example of exactly that: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Yes i declared the type as an Integer, but dose this Integer hold the value of the buffers and byes writing in `doInBackground()` ? Because after reading the docs again i can't find any connections to pass the value between `doInBackground()` to `doProgressUpdate()` ... unless if the `doProgressUpdate()` is meant to measure the procces of `doInBackground()`, is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

What's actually happening here is `textV.setText(pb.getProgress());` is calling

`setText(int resourceId)`

NOT

`setText(String text)`

You want to call:

```
textV.setText(Integer.toString(pb.getProgress()));
```

instead of

```
textV.setText(pb.getProgress());
```